# Extracting MySQL data as table content

Tags: php, mysql, sql

So I have a database from which I want to output data in the form of a table.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th class="tg-031e">Username</th>
    <th class="tg-031e">Password</th>
  </tr>
..
</table>
```

For now I get the data like this:

```
 <?php include 'connect.php';
 echo "<tr><td class='tg-031e'>";
 $SQL = "SELECT `Username` FROM `Users` WHERE ID=1";
 $exec = mysql_query($SQL, $connection);
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($exec)){
    echo $row['Username'] . "</td>";
 } ?>
```

However, in that case I need to echo out each column independently. How can I make PHP dynamically create an HTML table row with the information from the database whenever new data is present in the MySQL columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

modify your php code like this:

```
 <?php include 'connect.php';

   $SQL = "SELECT `Username` FROM `Users` WHERE ID=1";
   $exec = mysql_query($SQL, $connection);

   echo "<table>";
   echo "<tr>";
   echo "<th class="tg-031e">Username</th>";
   echo "<th class="tg-031e">Password</th>";
   echo "</tr>";    

   while($row = mysql_fetch_array($exec)){
      //add as many fields in record, i.e: username, password... etc.
      echo "<tr>";
      echo "<td class='tg-031e'>" . $row['Username'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td class='tg-031e'>" . $row['Password'] . "</td>";
      echo "</tr>"; 
   }

   echo "</table>";  

 ?>
```

Comment: Does the job :) Thanks.

Comment: @JessieStalk I'm glad it helped. Well, I don't see any CSS rules mentioned here. They should work fine if they're loaded in Browser. You can use browser's developer tool (usually on F12 key) to check if CSS styles are loaded.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php include 'connect.php';

$SQL = "SELECT `Username`, Password FROM `Users`";
$exec = mysql_query($SQL, $connection);
echo "<table><tr><td class="tg-031e">Username</td><td class="tg-031e">Password</td></tr>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($exec))
{
    echo "<tr><td class='tg-031e'>";
    echo $row['Username'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td class='tg-031e'>".$row['Password'] . "</td></tr>";
 }
echo "</table>";

?>
```

Comment: But ID is not dynamic. How could this echo new entries automatically while I'm selecting ID=1

Comment: What do you mean by not dynamic. Do you want to list all the entries in the table or only one entry.

Comment: All entries. If a new one is made, PHP should add it to the page.

Comment: Updated the answer. Now it will show all the entries(with new ones)